# Get package name and version of Parent Application from it's dependency

Tags: android

I am developing an android-library project which is then can be added as a module dependency to android-UI project. May I know, is there a way to get a package name and version of Parent project from the module dependency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a `Context`, call `getPackageName()` on the `Context` to find out the package name of the app. Given the `Context` and the package name, you can call `getPackageManager().getPackageInfo()` on the `Context` to get a `PackageInfo` object for the app, which contains `versionCode` and `versionName`.

Comment: I don't know package name for it and getPackageInfo() requires packageName

Comment: @Akshay: Quoting the first sentence of my answer: "**Given a `Context`, call `getPackageName()` on the `Context` to find out the package name of the app**".

Comment: @CommonsWare I have an App2 which is downloaded from App1, how can I get the version of App1? (You can imagine this as downloading App from play store but in actual the App1 is not play store)

Comment: @AsthaGarg: You would use other methods on `PackageManager`.